# matplotlib negative labels cannot parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

**How can I convert negative matplotlib labels to numbers?**

[image]

I created the above histogram with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(sub_df['Avg_cost_per_stay'], rwidth=0.8)
plt.title('Avg Cost Per Stay')
plt.show()
```

I wanted to change the x-tick labels to display thousands (16K, 18K, 20K ...). After trying fancier methods, I opted for the following brute-force approach:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([str(int(label.get_text())/1000)+' K' for label in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```

However, it threw an error. After separating out the loop, I found that the part `int(label.get_text())` threw the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '−200000'`

Ignoring the fact that -200K is not a label in my graph (???), further testing showed that the problem was that the negative sign used by matplotlib was not the one used normally. The following code (using the same graph info):

```
    first_label = ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()
    print(first_label[0] == '-')
    print(ord(first_label[0]))
    print(ord('-'))
```

yields the following output:

```
False
8722
45
```

Clearly, the problem is that the negative matplotlib uses in its labels is not the standard 'minus' sign.

**How does one parse negative values in matplotlib?** Parsing both with `float` and `int` yield the same error.

<s>As a bonus, if anyone has suggestions at solving the original problem (turning 1000, 2000... into 1K, 2K...), I'd love to hear them. Whether it is general to multiple magnitudes at once (K, M, G...), or hard-coded at one, either would be helpful.</s>

**Edit**: Seems like there are good answers that already exist for the bonus question. So, just address the first question. How can I convert negative matplotlib labels into numbers, given that they use a different minus sign than python can parse?

Comment: If you want to parse these strings, you can replace the unicode minus sign with the ascii version: `int(label.get_text().replace('\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-'))`. But note that to modify the tick labels, it is highly recommended to work with the tick formatters. `set_xticklabels` should only be used when you want to set strings unrelated to the numeric value.